# 【React-native】undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new to react-native. I use react-native-side-menu to create a drawer and I **add a bottom on the left side to skip to another page**. when I push the bottom, the error code appeared. However, **if I put the bottom in the homepage, it works.** Why if I put it in the drawer it will crash?

This is route stack
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';


import HomeScene from './homeScene';
import LoginScene from './loginScene';
import RegisterScene from './registerScene';
import TimetableScene from './timetable';
import ChatScene from './ChatScene';
import LeftMenu from './LeftMenu';


const SimpleApp = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScene,
      navigationOptions: {  
          headerTitle: 'Login',  
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScene,
      navigationOptions: {  
          header: null, 
      }
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScene,
      navigationOptions: {  
          headerTitle: 'Register',  
      }
    },
    Timetable: {
      screen: TimetableScene,
      navigationOptions:{
          headerTitle: 'Timetable',
      }
    },

    //The page I want to skip

    Chat: {
      screen: ChatScene,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerTitle: 'Chat',
      }
    }

    LeftMenu:{
      screen: LeftMenu
    }

});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SimpleApp);

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
    }
}
```

LeftScene.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    SectionList
} from 'react-native';

export default class LeftMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.selectSideMenu = this.selectSideMenu.bind(this);
    }



    selectSideMenu() {
        this.props.onSelectMenuItem();
    }

    Chat = () => {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;  
        navigate('Chat');  
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                //The bottom to skip to "Chat" page but will respond error

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.Chat}  
                    style={styles.button}>
                    <Text
                        style={styles.btText}>Chat</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**I think maybe the wrong code from the following code in LeftScene.js**

```
Chat = () => {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;  
        navigate('Chat');  
    }
```

The `this.props` can only get the value from the parent component. The parent component of LeftMenu is homeScene, homeScene has no navigation so it doesn't work. And because of App.js is parent component of homeScene, so if I put the skip bottom in homeScene it can work. **But I don't know how to figure out** it...

homeScene.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');


import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu'
import Menu from './LeftMenu'

export default class LeftSideMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
        }

        this.SelectMenuItemCallBack = this.SelectMenuItemCallBack.bind(this);
    }


    SelectMenuItemCallBack() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
        })
    }

    SelectToOpenLeftSideMenu() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: true,
        })
    }

    Chat = () => {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('Chat');
    }

    render() {

        const menu = <Menu onSelectMenuItem={this.SelectMenuItemCallBack} />;

        return (
            <SideMenu
                menu={menu}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                onChange={(isOpen) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isOpen: isOpen,
                    })
                }}
                menuPosition={'left'}
                openMenuOffset={0.75 * width}
                edgeHitWidth={200}

            >
                <View
                    style={styles.top}>
                    //The bottom to open the drawer
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.SelectToOpenLeftSideMenu()}
                        style={styles.Fbutton} >
                        <Text
                            style={styles.btText}>F</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>


                </View>

                //The bottom to skip to "Chat" page and works
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.Chat}
                        style={styles.button}>
                        <Text
                            style={styles.btText}>Chat</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>



            </SideMenu>

          );
    }
}
```

I expect the bottom to skip to "Chat" page on the homeScene can be put in the drawer

Comment: where is your route stack for navigation?can you please add it also in code!!

Comment: post your navigator.js file or file containing the route stack for navigation.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have put it. The App.js

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because your LeftScene.js is not a part of your stack just add **LeftScene.js** in **SimpleApp**.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code in homeScene.js

```
const menu = <Menu onSelectMenuItem={this.SelectMenuItemCallBack} />;
```

to the following

```
const menu = <Menu onSelectMenuItem={this.SelectMenuItemCallBack} navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
```